# Constraints on a Genetic Algorithm

Tags: excel, genetic-algorithm

I'm using SolveXL as an add-in for excel to do a multi-objective optimization. SolveXL solves it by applying the Non-dominated sorting genetic algorithm II (NSGA-II). My problem is with the constraints, when I have constraints to not exceed a value (less than 15) for example like this

```
=IF(C5>15;C5-15;0)
```

The software give me all solutions satisfying this. But when I want the solutions to be greater than a value (15)

```
=IF(C5<15;15-C5;0)
```

I don't get any solution with infeasibility zero. I'm sure I'm computing it right because I tried it with a small example.

Could it not be working because of the complexity of my excel computations?

Comment: Are you sure the syntax is right? `IF()` uses commas to separate the condition, true value and false value, not semicolon `;`

Comment: on mine it uses semicolon `;`

Comment: Oh ok then... just making sure it wasn't a syntax issue. Portuguese Excel?

Comment: Yes, Portuguese excel